# Is the syntax of my for-loop in R correct?

Tags: r, for-loop

My data is as follows (I call it data1):

```
X_4_2_1_a  X_4_2_2_a
5          7
999        999
998        998
2          998
1          NA
NA         999
```

I want to apply the following function to the data:

```
na.zero <- function (x) {
  x[is.na(x)] <- 0
  return(x)
}
```

And I want to use the following loop:

```
for (i in seq(1, 2, 1)) {
  data1$X_4_2_i_a <- na.zero(data1$X_4_2_i_a)
}
```

But it is not working. Could someone please assist?

Comment: data1$X_4_2_i_a is a literal, i.e. the _i_ is not recognized. In order to address a column in a dataframe you need to put df[i]. BTW: loops don't have a good reputation in R - I'd suggest to familiarize with the functional programming paradigm favored in R. For replacing NAs this function may be very helpful: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/replace_na.html

Comment: Thanks, but since my example is just a toy example, there are far more columns in my actual work. I would need a loop, otherwise it would take a lot of time to do it manually.

Comment: Loops have an unnecessarily bad reputation in R - it is generally the practices around loops that are detrimental. In fact, most functional approaches are very similar to loops in terms of computation anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with the variable you are trying to access in the data frame, you trying to access `X_4_2_i_a` which is not increment `i` in each iteration because its a string; Which is not the way to iterate on increasing labels in data frame.

You can consider creating a variable in each iteration using `paste` and then access it

> paste("X_4_2_", i, "_a", sep = "")

```
na.zero <- function (x) {
  x[is.na(x)] <- 0
  return(x)
}

df = data.frame("X_4_2_1_a"=c(5,999,998,2,1,NA), "X_4_2_2_a"=c(5,999,998,NA,1,NA))

for (i in seq(1, 2, 1)) {
    nn = paste("X_4_2_", i, "_a", sep = "")
    df[nn] <- na.zero(df[nn])
}


print(df)
```

will produce:

```
  X_4_2_1_a X_4_2_2_a
1         5         5
2       999       999
3       998       998
4         2         0
5         1         1
6         0         0
```

A solution that doesnt invovle loop is:

```
df = sapply(df, na.zero)
print(df)
```

which will produce the same output

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your plan was to apply your function to both columns of your `data.frame()`. Right now you are not specifying what to iterate over.

```
for (i in seq(1, 2, 1)) {
  data1[, i] <- na.zero(data1[, i])
}
# Your data.frame after running the loop
  X_4_2_1_a X_4_2_2_a
1         5         7
2       999       999
3       998       998
4         2       998
5         1         0
6         0       999
```

To iterate over columns you can use `[`. Where the first value represents the row and the second the column. Accordingly, `[, i]` means: apply your function to the first, then second column and over all rows.

---

Additionally, it is also worth mentioning that R offers the apply family to solve problems like this.

An apply family solution to your problem would be a little more code efficient:

```
apply(data1, 2, na.zero)
# Where 2 represent an iteration over columns
  X_4_2_1_a X_4_2_2_a
1         5         7
2       999       999
3       998       998
4         2       998
5         1         0
6         0       999
```

---

Last and surely not least is the option to skip the looping and only use indexing:

```
data1[is.na(data1)]<- 0
#
  X_4_2_1_a X_4_2_2_a
1         5         7
2       999       999
3       998       998
4         2       998
5         1         0
6         0       999
```

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate this question is more about application of functions in loops, but here is a simple, vectorised, Base R solution to achieve the same result:

```
df <- replace(df, is.na(df), 0)
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(X_4_2_1_a = c(5, 999, 998, 2, 1, 0), X_4_2_2_a = c(7, 
999, 998, 998, 0, 999)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```